# Extracting SharePoint data on daily basis

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, export, query-string, csv

I want to export my SharePoint document library data on daily basis and csv file need to be save as naming convention as "Dataname_yyyyMMdd". As per my below script, it need to export data from the sharepoint library into one CSV file as name "Data_yyyyMMdd". Then it need to imports the data from "Data_yyyyMMdd" and adds "header" to the file and then export to new final output CSV as name "DataName_yyyyMMdd".

While running the script i am getting only one file as "Data_yyyyMMdd". The data from file was not importing to final csv file and its not generating the final output file "DataName_yyyyMMdd".  Please correct me if doing wrong in script. Please share me correct script.

### Powershell script

```
$web = get-spweb $siteUrl

$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq $listTitle}

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 

$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><FieldRef Name='DocumentSetDescription'/>"

$query.RowLimit=5000

do

$ListName1 = "Data"

$ExportFolder1 = “C:\Users\”

$ExportName1 = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”

$ExportPath1 = $ExportFolder1 + $ListName1 + $ExportName1 + “.csv”

$ListName = "Dataname_"

$ExportFolder = “C:\Users\csv\”

$ExportName = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”

$ExportPath = $ExportFolder + $ListName + $ExportName + “.csv”

{

    $caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query)

    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition=$caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

    $listItemsTotal = $caseLibItems.Count

    $x = 0

    for($x=0;$x -lt $listItemsTotal; $x++)

    {

        $Description = $caseLibItems[$x]["DocumentSetDescription"]

        $str = ""

        if('$Description' -ne $null)

        {

            $Description = $Description -replace "`n"," " -replace "`r"," "

            $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString() + '}' + $Description

        }

        else

        {

            $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()

        }

Write-Output $str | Out-File $ExportPath1 -Append  

}

} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

Import-csv $ExportPath1 -delimiter "}" -Header "Number", "Description"  | export-csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation  


Write-Host "Exiting"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the PowerShell as below.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue
$siteUrl="http://sp2013/sites/team"
$listTitle="DL"
$web = get-spweb $siteUrl
$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq $listTitle}
$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
$query.ViewFields = ""
$query.RowLimit=5000
$ListName1 = "Data"
$ExportFolder1 = "C:\Users\"
$ExportName1 = Get-Date -f "yyyyMMdd"
$ExportPath1 = $ExportFolder1 + $ListName1 + $ExportName1 + ".csv"
$ListName = "Dataname_"
$ExportFolder = "C:\Users\csv\"
$ExportName = Get-Date -f "yyyyMMdd"
$ExportPath = $ExportFolder + $ListName + $ExportName + ".csv"
do
{
    $caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query)
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach($item in $caseLibItems)
    {
        $Description = $item["DocumentSetDescription"]
        $str = ""
        if('$Description' -ne $null)
        {
            $Description = $Description -replace "`n"," " -replace "`r"," "
            $str = $item["LinkFilename"].ToString() + '}' + $Description
        }
        else
        {
            $str = $item["LinkFilename"].ToString()
        }
        Write-Output $str | Out-File $ExportPath1 -Append
    }
}while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
Import-csv $ExportPath1 -delimiter "}" -Header "Number", "Description" | export-csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Exiting"
```

[image]